# Can we recover a frame from a paint.exe process dump

Tags: memory, volatility, memory-footprint

When a paint.exe process crashes in a system is it possible to recover the drawing we are working on using the raw memory dump?....maybe by using volatility or other tools...also please mention how we can completely recover the frame

I tried to check for temp .bmp files if it got saved to the cache but no use.